# how to make download script in php

Tags: php

i want to make a download link in my page,
the user upload text file to the server,i want to download that files,
plz help me i new to php,

Comment: Your question is very vague and contains no detail. The best Stack Overflow questions describe a use case (like you did, but with more detail and fewer lazy shortcuts in English), followed by your current approach, followed by the ways in which your approach is not currently producing the desired behaviour. Sometimes a theory about the problem comes with it too. Questions like "how do I do this" with no indication that you've done some research or had a go yourself usually do not attract productive answers (this is _not_ a message board). Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) properly then print the [file contents](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: +1 it works for every MIME TYPE, not just for text.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the mime type and file size, then set the correct headers before sending the file. Try this:

```
function sendFile($file) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    header('Content-type: ' . finfo_file($finfo, $file));
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
    $filename = basename($file);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
    fpassthru($file);
    finfo_close($finfo);
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in...

Comment: [finfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) is PHP 5.3+, sorry. Use `mime_content_type($file)` if you're using another version of PHP

Comment: +1 that's better. btw, i'm using 5.2.9.